# jQuery: Add click functionality to images to open/close a menu

Tags: jquery, menu, html-lists

I'm building Javascript-based menu and have gotten somewhat stuck with my jQuery code, which goes as follows:

```
// Add <img> tags
$(".menu-block-wrapper").find('li').not('.leaf').prepend('<img src="plus-sign.png"/>');

// Add clicking functionality to images
$(".menu-block-wrapper").find('li').not('.leaf > img').click(
     function(event) {
       $('ul', this).first().toggle();

       var ul = $('ul', this).first();

       if (ul.is(":hidden")) {
        $('img', this).first().attr( "src", "plus-sign.png" );
       } else {
        $('img', this).first().attr( "src", "minus-sign.png" );
       }

       event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Running this code in my test page ([jQuery Test Page](http://raegquit.com/beerdude26/javascript/domblobje.html)), I get satisfactory results. *(Note that other functionality, such as giving expanded menu items the proper icon, is handled by other code, so don't worry about that.)*

However, the clicking functionality is applied to the entire `<li>` tag. I want the clicking functionality to only apply to the `<img>` tag. My lack of knowledge of jQuery seems to be limiting me here, as everything I have tried broke the clicking functionality.

It may be handy to use my [jQuery Test Page](http://raegquit.com/beerdude26/javascript/domblobje.html) to assert your proposed changes. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
$(".menu-block-wrapper").find('li img').not('.leaf > img').click( ...
```

This will define the click function on images nested inside list-items that are not immediate-childen of an element with class-name "leaf"

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to break the code inside the function. I take it I have to put `.parent()` somewhere to access the `<ul>` that is inside the `<li>`, but I'm struggling a bit here.

Comment: $(this).parent()  will get you the ul,  if the ul is the the item's parent. If the element you need is an ancestor higher up the DOM, then $(this).closest('ul') will select the ul that is the fewest steps up the chain from $(this).

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want to achieve precisely, but your use of $('ul', this).first() gets you the first occurance of a ul nested *inside* of *this*, and since you're modifying click for $(".menu-block-wrapper").find('li').not('.leaf > img'), *this* means all list-itmes  that are inside of a .block-wrapper.

Comment: Note: .find('li').not('.leaf > img') gets you the exact same set as the more simple .find('li') because an image cannot be a list-item. What you specified with the former, in English, is "get me all list-items that are not images nested (as child) inside of a .leaf. But no image can be a list-item anyway.